# How to replace the content of one fragment with another in TabsLayout?

Tags: java, android

I use a tablayout with two tabs. Each tab has a viewpager fragment. The code:

```
ALoginFragment AFragment = new ALoginFragment();
BLoginFragment BFragment = new BLoginFragment();
SectionsPageAdapter sectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
sectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(AFragment, "A");
sectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(BFragment, "B");
viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPageAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

The `SectionsPageAdapter` is my custom sections page adapter. The code:

```
public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

When I click some button in fragment `A` I want to replace the content of tab `A` with tab `C`. I tried;

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(fragmentView.getId(), new CLoginFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Where save `fragmentView` in the `A`'s `onCreateView` method. But `fragmentView.getId()` is `-1` for some reason. How can I replace the content of `A` with `C`?

Answer (score 0):

to replace fragment which are inside viewpager put this function in `SectionsPageAdapter`

```
public void replaceFragment(int position,Fragment newFragment ){
    mFragmentList.set(position, newFragment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

then call it with the position of fragment that need to be changed and the newFragment

```
sectionsPageAdapter.replaceFragment(0,new CFragment());// replace ALoginFragment which is at zero index with CFragment
```

Comment: Oh thanks! What would be the easiest way to get to `sectionsPageAdapter` from the fragment? As you use it in the parent activity. Also, Can you show how you add support to the "back button"? Should I remove it from the `mFragmentList`?

Comment: send an event from child fragment to its parent through interface or follow this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between) then if you define your `sectionsPageAdapter` as global variable you can then use it